# How to lauch java program on server from web page

Tags: java, web, hosting

I have a simple java program that take some parameters to create an image. I want to set up a website in which the user can choose the parameters and, from his ok pressed, the server runs the program. When the program has finished, an image is on the server so the web user can see the result. How can I do that? Which technology I need? Something like JSP or only java installed on the server? Normally, hosting services have this possibility by default or I have to choose some advanced options? Just to have an idea... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with java, but also with php if you need it (php is generally more available and in my opinion quicker to setup).
You have your form send data as GET / POST request;
at the other end you have a web/application server receive the data (some kind of REST service or just a plain script), execute your image generating routine/program and then take this image and return it through http.

Comment: Can I run java from php code? I need some permission to use java on the server-side?

Comment: That depends on the service you're relying on. For example having a VPS totally allows you to do whatever you want as if you had your application on your own PC. However basic hosting plans only allow you to upload your website/application into your private space via ftp (for example) and execute it in a sandbox thus blocking access to any file (unless generated by your application or available in your private space)

Comment: Yes you can execute your java program as if it was any other program. Using for example `string exec ( string $command [, array &$output [, int &$return_var ]] )` or `string shell_exec ( string $cmd )` and passing your command (`java -jar whatever`)